# XSL template to javascript function

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

Here is my xml template:

```
    <xsl:template name="paragraphs">
    <xsl:param name="class" />
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&#10;')">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(substring-before($text,'&#10;')) &gt; 0"><p class="{$class}"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'&#10;')" /></p></xsl:if>
    <xsl:call-template name="paragraphs"><xsl:with-param name="class" select="$class" /><xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&#10;')" /></xsl:call-te$
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><p class="{$class}"><xsl:value-of select="$text" /></p></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Here is how I am using it in the `xsl stylesheet`

```
   <xsl:call-template name="paragraphs"><xsl:with-param name="text" select="./comment" /></xsl:call-template>
```

Now I need to convert the template into javascript. I honestly don't know how to do this.

I'd love some assistance on this.

Comment: @dandavis thanks. i removed that from the question. i really need assistance converting this to javascript it looks like a recursive function

Comment: it doesn't need to be recursive in JS, just split the lines `str.split("\n")`, iterate `lines.map`, and wrap each one with a p tag before re`join('\n')`ing